# Segfault when calling glGenFramebuffers()?

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl, glew

I wanted to do some 2D on top of 3D so I could do a decent GUI. So I created the textures and so on.

I can compile the code, it generates no errors.  But when I run the program all goes right until I call this:

```
glGenFramebuffers(1, &fb);
```

Then this appears:

```
error 139 segmentation fault (core dumped).
```

Does someone know what's wrong with the code?

```
std::cout << "test1" << std::endl;

unsigned int fb;
glGenFramebuffers(1, &fb);
std::cout << "test2" << std::endl;
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, fb);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, renderTexture.getId(), 0);
```

The "test1" text is displayed, but the "test2" is not.

CODE:

game.cpp

```
#include "game.h"

game::game(){
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    SDL_Surface* screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(1000, 600, 32, SDL_SWSURFACE|SDL_OPENGL);

    glClearColor(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);

    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(45, 1000.0/600.0, 1.0, 500.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}

game::~game(){
    SDL_Quit();
}

void game::start(){
    Uint32 start;
    SDL_Event event;

    texture renderTexture = texture();
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, 1000, 600, 0, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);

    std::cerr << "test1" << std::endl;

    unsigned int fb;
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &fb);
    std::cerr << "test2" << std::endl;
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, fb);
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, renderTexture.getId(), 0);

    bool running = true;
    while (running){
        start = SDL_GetTicks();

        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)){
            switch (event.type){
                case SDL_QUIT:
                    running = false;
                    break;
            }
        }

        update();
        show(fb);
        showMenu();

        SDL_GL_SwapBuffers();
        if (1000/30 > (SDL_GetTicks()-start)){
            SDL_Delay(1000/30 - (SDL_GetTicks()-start));
        }
    }
}

void game::update(){

}

void game::show(unsigned int fb){

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fb);

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();
}

void game::showMenu(){
    bindWindowAsRenderTarget();

    glViewport(0, 0, 1000, 600);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0.0, 1000.0, 0.0, 600.0, -1.0, 1.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}

void game::bindWindowAsRenderTarget(){
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
    glViewport(0, 0, 1000, 600);
}
```

game.h

```
#ifndef GAME_H_INCLUDED
#define GAME_H_INCLUDED

#include <iostream>

#include <SDL/SDL.h>

#include <GL/glew.h>

#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>

#include "texture.h"

class game{
    void update();
    void show(unsigned int fb);
    void showMenu();

    void bindWindowAsRenderTarget();

    public:
        game();
        ~game();

        void start();
};

#endif // GAME_H_INCLUDED
```

main.cpp

```
#include "game.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    game g;
    g.start();

    return 0;
}
```

texture.cpp

```
#ifndef TEXTURE_H_INCLUDED
#define TEXTURE_H_INCLUDED

#include <SDL/SDL.h>

#include <GL/glew.h>

#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>

class texture{
    unsigned int id;

    public:
        texture();
        ~texture();

        void loadImage(const char* filename);
        unsigned int getId();
};

#endif // TEXTURE_H_INCLUDED
```

texture.cpp

```
#include "texture.h"

texture::texture(){
    glGenTextures(1, &id);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, id);
}

texture::~texture(){
    glDeleteTextures(1, &id);
}

void texture::loadImage(const char* filename){
    SDL_Surface* img = SDL_LoadBMP(filename);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, img->w, img->h, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_6_5, img->pixels);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    SDL_FreeSurface(img);
}

unsigned int texture::getId(){
    return id;
}
```

Comment: Do not use `std::cout` to debug. It might not get executed. Use a debugger, or `std::cerr` instead. The bug could be elsewhere in next lines.

Comment: Show us the code necessary to fully compile `main()`, aka a [mcve]. Seg Faults in OpenGL are usually the product of an incorrect call many lines *before* the line where it crashes, and we need to see the full program to properly identify the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Dollars to donuts](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bet_a_dollar_to_a_doughnut#English) you're `#include`ing a [GL extension loader (GLEW, GLAD, etc.)](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library) and then:

1. Trying to init it before you have a current GL context (leaving function pointers like `glGenFramebuffers()` NULL), or
2. Forgetting to init it entirely, or
3. (Unlikely, unless you're doing something silly like trying to use OpenGL via remote desktop) correctly initing your extension loader but using a GL implementation that doesn't support core FBOs

**EDIT** Oh hey it's #2.

You need to call [`glewInit()`](http://glew.sourceforge.net/basic.html) after `SDL_SetVideoMode()`.  You should also use the GLEW version checking functions to verify that the version of the underlying GL implementation supports core FBOs (they went in in OpenGL 2.1 IIRC).

Comment: Thank you so much! It's solved now.

Comment: just for another possibility I used GLAD, fogot that I specified gl version 2.0 in the GLAD config, created a gl 4.3 context and then ran into this error.